# Complexity of two algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am studying algorithms complexity, and I have a question about the difference between the following two algorithms:

Algorithm #1:

```
sum = 0
i = 1

while (i < n) {

   for j = 1 to i {
       sum = sum + 1
   }

   i = i*2;
}

return sum
```

Algorithm #2:

```
sum = 0
i = 1

while (i < n) {

   for j = 1 to n {
       sum = sum + 1
   }

   i = i*2;
}

return sum
```

The only difference is the 'for' loop, but what is the difference between the time complexity of these algorithms ? When do I have to multiply or add the complexity of nested loops?

Comment: Not O(n^2) but O(logN) for first and O(NlogN) for second I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say for simplisity that n is a power of `2` i.e. `2^k`. Then it is obvious that outer loop will proceed k times and on each step inner loop will proceed:

```
1 to 1 i.e. 2^0
1 to 2 i.e. 2^1
1 to 4 i.e. 2^2
...
1 to        2^k
```

So we just need to find the sum `2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^k`

It is knows as `2^(k+1) - 1 = 2^k * 2 - 1 = 2*n + 1`

So omitting constants we get `O(n)`

Second one is simple. Outer loop is `log(n)`, inner `n` so you get `O(n*log(n))`.